# vite dev dynamically set index.html src="..." by cli args

Tags: javascript, html, vite

I have a repository of html canvas animations

```
├── animations
│   └── animation1.js -- querySelector('canvas'), draw stuff to it
│   └── animation2.js -- querySelector('canvas'), draw stuff to it
├── index.html
├── package.json
└── vite.config.ts
```

currently, the `src=` inside of `index.html` is hardcoded to be `animation1.js`

```html
  <body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="../animations/animation1.js"></script>
  </body>
```

so running `npm run dev` (`vite`) always results in that animation being the one shown in the browser.

I want the value of `src` to be generated dynamically based on the first cli argument passed,
such that running
`npm run dev animation1`
will effectively behave like

```html
    <script type="module" src="../animations/animation1.js"></script>
```

and
`npm run dev animation2`
will effectively behave like

```html
    <script type="module" src="../animations/animation2.js"></script>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to dynamically generate the src attribute of the  tag in your HTML based on a CLI argument. To achieve this, you can use Node.js and a script that reads the CLI argument and updates the HTML file accordingly before running your Vite development server.

```
**1. Create script for update index.html file**

    // updateScriptSrc.js
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    
    // Read the CLI argument
    const argument = process.argv[2];
    
    // Define the path to the HTML file
    const htmlFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
    
    // Define a mapping of arguments to script paths
    const scriptPaths = {
      animation1: '../animations/animation1.js',
      animation2: '../animations/animation2.js',
      // Add more mappings for other animations if needed
    };
    
    // Check if the argument corresponds to a valid script path
    if (scriptPaths.hasOwnProperty(argument)) {
      const scriptPath = scriptPaths[argument];
    
      // Read the HTML file content
      fs.readFile(htmlFilePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
    
        // Replace the src attribute in the HTML content
        const updatedHtml = data.replace(
          /<script type="module" src="[^"]*"><\/script>/,
          `<script type="module" src="${scriptPath}"></script>`
        );
    
        // Write the updated HTML back to the file
        fs.writeFile(htmlFilePath, updatedHtml, 'utf8', (err) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          console.log(`Updated ${htmlFilePath} with ${argument} script.`);
        });
      });
    } else {
      console.error(`Invalid argument: ${argument}`);
    }`enter code here`
    
**2. Update your package.json scripts**.
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node updateScriptSrc.js animation1 && vite",
    // Other scripts...
  },
  // Other configurations...
}
```

Comment: Cool, but this does feel like a hacky solution. I'm hoping for an official Vite tool, plugin, or config option that i can use to get this behavior.